# Finding Factorial Trailing Zeros from Huge Numbers without calculating the Factorial Java

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

Some of the numbers being tested will result in factorials in the digits of 10,000+ so calculating this to find the trailing zeros seems to not be possible. How can I find the number of trailing zeros without calculating for the factorial.

```
        long sum = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
            sum *= i;
        }
        char[] length = String.valueOf(sum).toCharArray();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = length.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
                if (length[i] == '0')
                    count++;
                if (length[i] != '0')
                    break;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share a sample input and output?

Comment: *Is* there such a thing as a "*trailing*" zero - how does that work?

Comment: Use Legendre's formula with p = 5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the solution is (integer overflow is not covered):

```java
public static int zerosFactorialTrailing(int n) {
    int fives = 0;
    for (int i = 5; i <= n; i *= 5) {
        fives += n / i;
    }
    /*
     * There are always more twos than fives
     *
    int twos = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i *= 2) {
        twos += n / i;
    }
    return Math.min(twos, fives);
    */
    return fives;
}
```